# how to change herkou region from us to eu of a pre deployed app withou lossing any app data

Tags: python, django, heroku

i have pre deployed app on heroku but b default it region is us and i am from india so my load time is very much then expected so i want to change region to eu which exactly half of distance from us so my load time will improved

i also tried the documentation https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-migration but i falied to migrate if someone did it before please guide me step by step it would be very helpful for me and other future reader

thank you for your time

i know a similar question asked before but there also refering to documentation which i tried so i am looking for step by step guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is step by step guide oh how to do it
for changing heroku region from us to eu you cannot do it from setting so there is no such option provided b heroku fo changing app region from us to eu do in oder to din that you have to create a app for eu region like that

```
heroku create <appname> --region eu
```

but if you want to same name change name of your app and create a new app with same name here is the documentation https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/renaming-apps

when you done with the name
you have to install a heroku fork plugin

```
heroku plugins:install heroku-fork
```

then for forkin you your existing us app to you new eu region app

```
heroku fork --from sourceapp --to targetapp --region eu
```

but before forking please enable maintaince mode on your existing app
then do forking

after forking for migrating your previous app data
follow this article step https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-migration#database-preparation

then delete your previous app

```
heroku apps:destroy
```

if you are using custom domain
then manage you dns acc to that

Answer (score 1):

What kind of issues did you face? If the (deprecated) migration functionality is not working, you can still migrate it manually.

1. Create new app in correct region
2. Add all addons & set everything up
3. Set old app to maintance mode
4. Export data from old app's database
5. Import data to new app' database
6. Adjust dns settings

Comment: after doing the same things thin i got the ssl issue